# How to assign a value to an enum?

Tags: c#, enums

Trying to assign a value to the `_cat.CatType.`

I was wondering how to do this without getting a null reference error?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    private CatClass _cat;
    public void Main()
    {
        _cat.CatType = CatType.Active;

        Console.WriteLine(_cat.CatType.ToString());
    }

    public enum CatType
    {
        New,
        Active,
        Inactive
    }

    public class CatClass
    {
        public CatType CatType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally I want to assign it something like this `_cat.CatType = CatType.Active`

Comment: by creating an instance of the CatClass.....

Comment: `private CatClass _cat;` does not create a `CatClass` object, it only creates a field which you can reference `CatClass` objects in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *initialise* it with the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-operator) keyword

> Used to create objects and invoke constructors

```
public void Main()
{
    _cat = new CatClass();
    _cat.CatType = CatType.Active;

    Console.WriteLine(_cat.CatType.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Ah so simple can't believe I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class.

```
private CatClass _cat = new CatClass;
```

Comment: oops missed a bit :) `new CatClass();`

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate `_cat` with the [`new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new) keyword first:

```
_cat = new CatClass
{
    CatType = CatType.Active
};
```